# Accepting JSON data in Rails-MySQL

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json

I need to send variables from my Android application to MySQL database. I have written server side code in RubyonRails. I am planning to send variables through JSON. I am now confused on how to let ROR know which value is for which column.  My controller class is as below:

```
    class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  # GET /categories
  # GET /categories.json
  def index
    @categories = Category.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @categories }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/1
  # GET /categories/1.json
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @category }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/new
  # GET /categories/new.json
  def new
    @category = Category.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @category }
    end
  end

  # GET /categories/1/edit
  def edit
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /categories
  # POST /categories.json
  def create
    @category = Category.new(params[:category])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.save
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @category, status: :created, location: @category }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /categories/1
  # PUT /categories/1.json
  def update
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @category.update_attributes(params[:category])
        format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /categories/1
  # DELETE /categories/1.json
  def destroy
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @category.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to categories_url }
      format.json { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

I am passing 'create' method in url in order to execute below method

```
def create
        @category = Category.new(params[:category])

        respond_to do |format|
          if @category.save
            format.html { redirect_to @category, notice: 'Category was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @category, status: :created, location: @category }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @category.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

I understand `params[:category]` will accept json data send but I am not sure how to let ROR which all parameters are passed. There might be an instance when we have values for 2 columns and not for all columns defined in table. Do I need to specify column name in key while sending json data and send null values for columns whose value is not be send. Or just giving specific 2 column names with their values will suffice.

Also please let me know if any additional step to be done at server side or just directing to controller class with appropriate method name will work. Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just give the column names which have value. Rails saves automatically after the validation is passed.

In android app, call `http://yoursite:yourport/categories` with post method. It will execute `create` method of `CategoriesController`. Make sure you can receive correct json format parameters in your controller.